# Knockout certificate (Long) fell more than 6% even though the underlaying security rose 1.2%

Tags: stocks, options, stock-exchanges, call-options

I recently bought a knockout certificate for facebook. 
So far it has been doing great returning more then 200%.

But recently it has been doing something really strange. On Friday Facebook rose 1.2% but the knockout fell more then 6% !

You can have a look at it here (sorry I only found a German Site but the terms are all in English) 
http://knock-outs.finanztreff.de/dvt_einzelkurs_uebersicht.htn?seite=turbos&i=21746984

Could someone please explain to me what is happening here.

PS: Please no investment advice regarding Facebook ;)

Comment: What's a knockout certificate, pardon my ignorance?

Comment: Knock-out warrants are also leverage investment products but have several characteristics that differ from those of call or put warrants: - more: http://www.scoach.ch/en/know-how/product-know-how/leverage-product-with-knock-out/knock-out-warrants

Answer (score 1):

the knockout products look very cool, I am jealous that they do not trade on the US exchanges

since they do expire I assume that theta also applies to them, which means they lose value over time

one phenomenon is that on fridays, they such products lose value for all the UPCOMING days that the exchanges are closed. So your knockout lost value to account for friday night, saturday and sunday

Comment: I glanced at the link that described this product, what exactly do you find more appealing about these? I've traded US options for 30+ years, having a tough time getting my head around this newer one.

Comment: just the P/L curve at expiration, the lesser exposure to implied volatility, the amount of capital needed to initiate a position, the leverage.

Comment: cqm you are talking about options knockouts dont tend to too decrease in value over time becasue you are basically getting a loadn to buy the stock and the amount of your own caoital is the knockout barrier

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I like the simplicity of a knockout - google knockout vs option and you will find the pros and cons - in my opinion the biggest con is that they tend to be more expensive for a longterm investment